# what is the difference between DataSourceTransactionManager and ResourcelessTransactionManager?

Tags: spring, transactions, spring-batch, spring-transactions, transactionmanager

What is the difference between `org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager`
and `org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager`

```
<bean id="batchTransactionManager" class=
  "org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager" />
  
<bean id="batchJobLauncher"
  class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
    <property name="jobRepository" ref="batchJobRepository" />
    <property name="taskExecutor">
        <bean class="org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

In the above code is it correct to use resourcelesstransactionmanager?
Or should i use datasourcetransactionmanager?
What are the differneces and when to use them?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Spring Batch requires a `PlatformTransactionManager` to apply its transaction semantics when driving a job and interacting with the job repository.

`ResourcelessTransactionManager` is a No-Op implementation of `PlatformTransactionManager` which means there will be no real transaction ongoing against a transactional resource (hence the term `Resourceless`). You can use it when you don't really need (or care about) transactional behaviour, for example in tests/prototypes or when using a non-transactional job repository. This class is provided by Spring Batch and is not recommended to use for production.

`DataSourceTransactionManager` on the other hand is from Spring Framework and is used to drive transactions against a JDBC DataSource (which could be a real database or an in-memory one). This transaction manager is typically used in Spring Batch to store batch meta-data in a relational database as a job repository.